# Firebase storing data from textfield to Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following a guide and my goal is to be able to have two textfields that can save the name and email of the user to the Firebase Database or Storage. I am getting many errors and wanted to know what I could do to the code to fix it or if there was a better guide to follow for my goal.

https://medium.com/@felicity.johnson.mail/firebase-user-sign-up-login-data-management-992d778b167

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var textFieldName: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var textFieldEmail: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var labelNotification: UILabel!

        @IBAction func buttonAddSave(_ sender: UIButton) {

            let ref = Database.database().reference().root
            let key =   ref.child("names").childByAutoId().key
            guard let userKey = Auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

            ref.child("emails").child(userKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                var count = "0"
                if let value = snapshot.value as? [String] {
                    count = String[describing: value.count]
                }
                var newName = [String: String]()
                newName[count] = key
                ref.child("names").child(userKey).updateChildValues(newName)
                self.presentAlertWithTitle(title:"Congrats!", message: "You successfully joined the Mobile Development Club!")
            })
        }
```

Comment: That's a two year old tutorial. You should really start with the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once). Stating you are getting many errors doesn't help us to help you as we don't know what that means. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you tell us specifically what's wrong with your code and what it's supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's go taking each step individually.

First of all, is your user **Authenticated**? Because if he is not,
this line

`guard let userKey = Auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}`

will always return.

#### First

`count = String[describing: value.count]`

should be

`count = String(describing: value.count)`

#### Second

The `self.presentAlertWithTitle(title:"Congrats!", message: "You successfully joined the Mobile Development Club!")` probably isn't even implemented in your code - and it's not a `UIViewController` function.

#### Third and most important

I think you're really confused about all this **Firebase functions** that you're trying to implement, so I suggest you to just find a **better tutorial**. I can recommend you [this one](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios) - it's the *official*.